# PHP: Loading a html template from a .txt file and replacing the tag before sending an Email

Tags: php, templates, html-email

I'm currently creating a nice contact form on my website and I'm having some issues getting a html template to work.

The template itself is a .txt file containing validated HTML. Within this html is a tag

```
     [email_content].
```

This tag should be replaced with the content of the Email which is generated from a contact form on my website:

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" id="contact_form" name="contact_form">
        <div id="form_name_ctrl_group" class="control-group">
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <textarea class="input-xlarge" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Insert message here..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sky">Send</button>
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-sky">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

Upon submission, this form is validated using jQuery validate and then submitted via jQuery ajax using the serialize function. The serialized data is then sent to the following php function for use:

```
<?php
    function mailer_send($mailer_recipient, $mailer_subject, $mailer_message){
        $mailer_headers = 'From: webmaster@example.co.uk' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n"
        'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n' . "\r\n" 
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';
        mail($mailer_recipient, $mailer_subject, $mailer_message, $mailer_headers);
     }

$name = $_POST['inputName'];
$email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$message = strip_tags($_POST['inputMessage']);
$template = file_get_contents('email_templates/template.txt');
$template = str_replace('[email_content]',$message, $template);


     mailer_send('enquiries@example.co.uk','Test Email',$template);
 ?>
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to replace the tag [email_content] within the html template with the message that the user entered in the contact form. The template should then be used to send an email to my email account. My current issue is that i'm not actually receiving anything.

The script works without the template part (if I use $message in mailer_send) so what could be going wrong here?

My directory structure is as follows:

```
       /fnc
           mailer.php
           /email_templates
                template.txt
```

Additional:
    I get the following error message within my server logs:

```
   [19-Jul-2013 13:00:43 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/username/public_html/example/fnc/mailer.php on line 5
```

Comment: Have you checked that $template is being read properly by `file_get_contents`?

Comment: How would I do that? The process is run using ajax so I can't really do an echo.

Comment: No need. The error log on my server tells me if the function performed correctly or not. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few string concatenation operators, look at your error message:
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/username/public_html/example/fnc/mailer.php on line 5`

```
function mailer_send($mailer_recipient, $mailer_subject, $mailer_message){
    $mailer_headers = "From: webmaster@example.co.uk" . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($mailer_recipient, $mailer_subject, $mailer_message, $mailer_headers);
 }
```